# Green function formulation of quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, greens-functions, correlation-functions

Suppose that I am given the vacuum expectation value of time ordered products of position operators in Heisenberg picture. Given this Green's function, is it possible to obtain information about the energy eigenvalues by inserting a complete set of basis states? I am attaching the screenshot of the problem below:

[image]

I tried inserting the states, but could not figure out how we could gain information about the eigenvalues (and ultimately about the functional form of the Hamiltonian) if we are only given the Green functions.

Note: This is actually problem 1 of chapter 3 in Tom Bank's book on qft.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting problem. Could you please clarify what precisely is given as input (for those who don't have the book you mention to hand)? $\left\langle \varnothing \middle| Q(t_n) \dots Q(t_1) \middle| \varnothing \right\rangle$ for any $t_n \geq \dots \geq t_1$, with $\varnothing$ defined as the lowest energy eigenstate?

Comment: @Luzanne I have added a screen shot of the problem to my question. For your question, yes we are given the expectation value as you have rightly mentioned, with the the vacuum being the energy eigenstate of eigenvalue zero.

Comment: Thanks, that's clearer. I suggested an edit, since your original formulation could suggest that the functional form of the Hamiltonian would also be part of the input.

Comment: This answer by Marek may be of help: http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/4611/31895

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be possible to recover the energy eigenvalues just from the 2-points function. For $t_2 \geq t_1$, using that $H \left|0\right\rangle = 0$, I have:
$$
\left\langle 0 \middle| \,\hat{x}(t_2) \, \hat{x}(t_1)\, \middle| 0 \right\rangle
=
\left\langle 0 \middle| \,\hat{x} \,e^{i \delta t H}\, \hat{x}\, \middle| 0 \right\rangle
=
\sum_n e^{i \delta t E_n}\, \left\langle 0 \middle| \,\hat{x} \, \middle| n \right\rangle \,\left\langle n \middle| \hat{x}\, \middle| 0 \right\rangle
=: G(\delta t)
$$
where $\delta t = t_2 - t_1 \geq 0$, $\hat{x} := \hat{x}(0)$ and $\left| n \right\rangle, E_n$ are the energy eigenvectors/eigenvalues. Since $\alpha_n := \left\langle 0 \middle| \,\hat{x} \, \middle| n \right\rangle \,\left\langle n \middle| \hat{x}\, \middle| 0 \right\rangle$ is *real*, we have $G(-\delta t) = \overline{G(\delta t)}$, so we know $G$ for all $\delta t \in \mathbb{R}$. Then its Fourier transform will be a sum of Dirac deltas localized at the $E_n$'s, with amplitudes $\alpha_n$.

I guess more information can be gained by looking at $3$-points functions and so on, ultimately recovering the full information on the theory from its Green functions.

To give a bit of context, this problem can be seen as a baby version of the reconstruction of a QFT from its path integral (à la [Osterwalder–Schrader reconstruction theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wightman_axioms)).